# Forms open and load very slow. Sometimes they won't open

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have a relatively small VB winforms project. 
It is currently used to launch numbers hyperlinks and some apps on a server.
There are a couple functions that do all the work, but the it really boils down to:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("iexplore.exe", urlVar)
```

or if it is an app sitting on the server, the variable passed into the function `appLinkVar` will contain the need file path to launch the application.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(appLinkVar)
```

The "items" are stored on a SQL Local Database (.mdf)

`Id, appName, appLink, appClickCount, appFavList,`and`decision`, which tells the function if it is calling a website or opening an executable.

Currently, there are forty rows in the database and I project 150+ in the end that need to be updated centrally and often (weekly). But that's a different question for later. The reason I added in it in this question was for insight as to why I am using a database instead of a Setting or XML file for some links. (better suggestions welcome)

My admin main form loads Visible = False and loads the icon in the system try. So you can't actually see the first form that opens. It is a hidden admin window  and it's main purpose is to put the icon in the system tray. The green RJ icon - http://snag.gy/VBa6c.jpg
Then all of the app interaction is around the notify icon. Example: the app loads on hover. right-click for settings and options etc.

Once the primary form loads, on mouse over the "Primary Label" for example and the white form to the left appears and so on. Not much to it. http://snag.gy/excKr.jpg

The Frequently Accessed items is currently stored on the database called appClickCount, this will be coming off of the database and to another recommended way of storing the data. But when I initially added the database, I noticed some lag in the main form loading. It would take it 5-7 seconds to populate the Frequently Accessed Items List and so on. So I changed the code from mainWindow.show() to mainWindow.visible(). Worked great for me. opened and closed very quickly. But after some use today by a tester, the application became almost unresponsive. He clicked on the notification icon numerous times and the app failed to load. Then threw a SQL time out error. It was the end of the day and I couldn't grab a screenshot.

I need to make this more reliable.

After some discussion the other day on SO, I was talking to someone that recommended I re-write the app in C# WPF, and that is definitely the plan. But I need this thing to past testing as is in VB this week. **Where can I start troubleshooting the delay in opening?** What other suggestions do you have to improve the application? Do I need to have an invisible form load first so I have access to a system tray icon or is there a better way?

I have talked to quite a few people on here lately and got some really good advice, I figured I would lay it all out here and see what input you guys can give a new guy... I'm also gonna go hang in the C# room for a little bit if you have any further questions.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: "Where can I start troubleshooting the delay in opening?" - StopWatch + print statements!

Comment: Sorry again @JohnSaunders :/ I really tried hard to work on my title and put a lot into the body... I'm trying sir :/

Comment: I shall start Google'ing @MitchWheat . Can you provide a tad more direction ?

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/stopwatch

Comment: It is not necessary to have a form in order to place an icon in the system tray.  You can just instantiate the NotifyIcon class directly, although I doubt that is causing your lag issues.  I would suggest get a good profiler and see where the problem actually is.  You can get a trial version of Ants profiler from Red-Gate or there are other profilers available as well.